# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 160

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

I am getting following error on product detail page for multiselect attributes.

```
Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 160

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 160

0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'strpos() expect...', '/home/xxxx...', 160, Array)

1 /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php(160): strpos(Array, ',')

2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/AbstractFrontend.php(331): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table->getOptionText(Array)

3 /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/AbstractFrontend.php(176): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend->getOption(Array)

4 /home/xxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php(84): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend->getValue(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))

5 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/xxxx/xxxx/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml(19): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes->getAdditionalData();
```

I am using magento 2.2.3 please help

Comment: add multiselect product attribute create code

Comment: @Pradeep Sanku Did you find a solution? I am having this issue also

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue in Magento 2.3.0 and was able to get it fixed by changing the `Table.php` file.

Before I explain what I did, let me preface it with you should never change core Magento file and should extend any changes into a custom module. But for me this is a small change that is needed due to an issue with the core code so it makes sense for to make the change directly, still not recommended.

Okay, so I needed to make two changes, one mentioned in another answer which is to change line 152 from

```
if(strpos($value, ',') !== false){`
```

to

```
if (is_array($value)) {
```

and then comment out line 154

```
//value = explode(',',$value);
```

as the explode function cannot accept an array as it's second parameter.

After making these changes I was able to browse again. I'm not entirely sure of any possible issues that this may bring up, but it has been working for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is magento2 bug. we should update following code

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $isMultiple = false;
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $isMultiple = true;
        $value = explode(',', $value);
    }

    $options = $this->getSpecificOptions($value, false);

    if ($isMultiple) {
        $values = [];
        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if (in_array($item['value'], $value)) {
                $values[] = $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return $values;
    }

    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if ($item['value'] == $value) {
            return $item['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```