# Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 157

Tags: magento2, module, array, product-detail-page

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/equpo/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 157

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/equpo/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 157
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'strpos() expect...', '/home/equpo/pub...', 157, Array)
#1 /home/equpo/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php(157): strpos(Array, ',')
#2 /home/equpo/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/AbstractFrontend.php(331): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table->getOptionText(Array)
#3 /home/equpo/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/AbstractFrontend.php(176): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend->getOption(Array)
```

when i open prouduct details page for all products

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $isMultiple = false;
    if (strpos($value, ',')) {
        $isMultiple = true;
        $value = explode(',', $value);
    }

    $options = $this->getSpecificOptions($value, false);

    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $value = [$value];
    }
    $optionsText = [];
    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if (in_array($item['value'], $value)) {
            $optionsText[] = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($item['label']);
        }
    }
```

how i can solve this???

Comment: What will you get in the $value ?

Comment: don't know  bro....

Comment: From where did u call this function ? please share the code

Comment: i did not call this function

Comment: Have you created any attribute ? what type of attribute is that?

Comment: no attribute is created

Comment: what is your magento version ?

Comment: magento 2.2.4.............

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same issue as [strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 160](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230306/strpos-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given-in-vendor-magento-module?rq=1)

As mentioned on the solution of the attached link it is a magento2 bug and the code should look like the following:

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $isMultiple = false;
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $isMultiple = true;
        $value = explode(',', $value);
    }

    $options = $this->getSpecificOptions($value, false);

    if ($isMultiple) {
        $values = [];
        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if (in_array($item['value'], $value)) {
                $values[] = $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return $values;
    }

    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if ($item['value'] == $value) {
            return $item['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```